# Receive 3rd Party Websocket Data on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm looking to connect to a public websocket and receive the data into AWS Lambda or SNS.

Looking at similar posts, it seems the only way to do this is via EC2, ECS etc. These posts were from a few years ago so I'd first like to see if anyone has found a way to do this in a serverless manor?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are thinking of doing in EC2/ECS you should be able to do in AWS Lambda + a Cloudwatch rule to run this websocket data ingestion logic on whatever schedule you need. That said Lambda functions are optimized for running burst workloads and handling non-steady traffic, if you need to maintain a consistent real-time connection to this websocket and dont want to manage servers, your best option will be **[Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/)**, **which offers serverless compute for containers** that you can use to build an application like yours.

Also, I highly recommend looking into **AWS Copilot** for a simple way to manage/deploy your application:  https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/